# Drawing a line in html

Tags: html

I'm quite new to HTML and I need to make a website for my school. For aesthetic purposes I want to put in a line between two bits of text, but when I try to, it just shows the code where I'm trying to put the line. This is the code:

CSS:

```
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <br>
        <p class='paragraph'>
            <strong><font size="40">WE'VE BEEN BUSY</font></strong>
        </p>hr { display: block; height: 1px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }
        <p class='paragraph'>
            <strong><font face="Trebuchet MS" size="40">CHECK IT OUT!</font></strong>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is what happens when I look at the page

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's CSS, not HTML.

Comment: That CSS determines how *any* HR will be rendered. You may want to specify `#my-hr-001` instead of hr, and in the HTML code, you place an element with that id - `<hr id="my-hr-001">` or `<div id="my-hr-001">`. Notice that the CSS has a # where the HTML does not. If you do not bother with CSS and place `<hr>` in the HTML, you'll get a default line.

Comment: show us your HTML code.

Comment: <tr>
  <td align="center">
   <br>
   <p class='paragraph'><strong><font size="40">WE'VE BEEN BUSY</font></strong></p>
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
   <p class='paragraph'><strong><font face="Trebuchet MS" size="40">CHECK IT OUT!</font></strong></p>
  </td>
 </tr>

Comment: Thanks, Iserni! It works!

Comment: to draw a line in html you use `<hr/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the line, you will have to put your code up there ^ in a `<style>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>HTML</h1>
<p>HTML is a language for describing web pages.</p>

<hr>

<h1>CSS</h1>
<p>CSS defines how to display HTML elements.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS stylesheets are prefered to inline style tags.

Comment: That's what I prefer, but for the sake of simplicity I would use the style tag. @Martin